# Androidx Preferences not incuding RingtonePreference

Tags: android, android-preferences, androidx, android-settings

I'm doing the settings activity for my app via code since the xml editor wont find any preferences but PreferenceScreen. Via code everything is working but I can not find the `RingtonePreferences` from `Androidx`, the only one I find is the one from `android.preference.RingtonePreference`.

I have this implementation.

```
implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha02"
```

`RingtonePreference` has not been added yet? or there is another preference under another name I can use in order to let users choose a notification sound. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> RingtonePreference has not been added yet?

Google has stated that [their libraries will not support `RingtonePreference`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37057453#comment2).

> or there is another preference under another name I can use in order to let users choose a notification sound

Use a `ListPreference`. Or use [this workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37057453#comment3). Or create a custom `Preference` that integrates with the ringtone APIs.

Comment: Did anybody dare to implement such a custom preference? As far as I understand they wanted to avoid "some awkward plumbing". The workaround is helpful but the preference summary does not get updated.

Comment: @yasd: I haven't seen one, though creating one using [this library](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-ringtone-picker) ought to be relatively easy.

Comment: changed <RingtonePreference to <Preference with android:key="@string/pref_notification_sound" but preference.getKey() = null. Any ideas?

Comment: @JimClermonts: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you can provide a [mcve].